# What does this mean? node.js this.queue(String(Number(msg) ^ 1));

Tags: node.js, sockets, stream, streaming

I'm investigating substack/shoe example code, especially node stream out out on browser side:

https://github.com/substack/shoe/blob/master/example/invert/client.js

```
stream.pipe(through(function (msg) {
    result.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
    this.queue(String(Number(msg)^1));
})).pipe(stream);
```

I undersand what

```
result.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
```

does, but I just can't figure out what

```
this.queue(String(Number(msg) ^ 1));
```

does along with

```
   .pipe(stream)
```

`queue` and `.pipe(stream)` back to stream slightly meaningful to me for stream control, but `String(Number(msg) ^ 1)` is the one I know nothing of. what is  `^ 1)`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume *msg* can be either "0” or "1”, and "^" here is a JavaScript XOR operator to flip its value, so 0^1 = 1, and 1^1=0.

Comment: Eah, now it perfectly makes sense. Thanks! @Noseratio